# Mocking Object list issue

Tags: apex, unit-test, map, test-setup, mock

This question is sort of a continuation to [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/313865/82119) question. I have this method:

```
public static void sendMail(List<Object> selectedRows) {
     if (selectedRows.size() > 0) {
          for (Object obj : selectedRows) {
               Map<Object, Object> mapJson = (Map<Object, Object>)obj;
               String title = (String)mapJson.get('title');
               String link = (String)mapJson.get('link');
          }
     }
}
```

I wanted to mock `selectedRows` list for testing. I did this:

```
List<Object> selectedRows = (List<Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped('[{"title":"Title1","link":"https://www.google.com"}]');
```

based on [the](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/313866/82119) answer. Also, I converted `Map<Object, Object>` to `Map<String, Object>` based on the suggestion in the answer. But, after that when I run the code, i am getting this error: `Invalid conversion from runtime type Map<ANY,ANY> to Map<String,ANY>`. So, I changed it back to `Map<Object, Object>`. Then, the **test** code throws this error: `Invalid conversion from runtime type Map<String,ANY> to Map<ANY,ANY>`.

So, the current situation is **either the code works or the test works, but not both.** How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shall work perfectly with above method.

```java
@isTest
    private static void testSendMail(){
        List<Map<Object, Object>> jsonMap = new List<Map<Object, Object>>();
        Map<Object, Object> tempMap = new Map<Object, Object>();
        tempMap.put('title'  , 'Title1');
        tempMap.put('link'  , 'https://www.google.com');
        jsonMap.add(tempMap);
        List<Object> selectedRows = (list<Object>)jsonMap;
        Q_313948.sendMail(selectedRows); //class in which sendMail is present
   }
```